# Highcharts: disable tick, but leave label

Tags: highcharts

I need to disable one particular tick, but leave it's label visible. Is it possible in HighCharts?

I use scatter plot.

Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omt4T.jpg

I need to get rid of ticks at 0, 0 point.

Comment: Perhaps you can demonstrate and give us a jsfiddle.net to see?

Comment: Don't think this is possible TBH without some CSS fiddling.

Comment: Couldn't create jsfiddle, because the project is too complex, but used your CSS suggestion and it worked :)

Comment: Sweet! Glad it helped :)